# Does lightgbm return predictions in order?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

I have a lightgbm multiclass classification model that I want to create a confusion matrix for. First step I want to just plot the predicted vs actual on a df though... my question is does lightgbm.predict return the predictions in order for the dataset you give it.

If you follow my code below, is my "predictions" section correctly matching the test data set row with the prediction row that corresponds to it?

Here is how I am creating my test and train set:

```
# split train and test into X and Y
X_train = train_data[:,0:(model.shape[1]-2)] ; Y_train = train_data[:,model.shape[1]-1] # python starts counting at 0
X_test = test_data[:,0:(model.shape[1]-2)] ; Y_test = test_data[:,model.shape[1]-1] # python starts counting at 0

#training and eval dataset
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(data = X_train, label = Y_train)
lgb_test = lgb.Dataset(data = X_test, label = Y_test)
```

running the model:

```
#run model
bst_model = lgb.train(params = parameters, train_set = lgb_train, num_boost_round = 1000, 
                      valid_sets = [lgb_train,lgb_test], early_stopping_rounds = 7) 
                      #categorical_feature = categoricals_vec)
```

and then the predictions:

```
#Predictions
preds = bst_model.predict(X_test)
preds_df =  pd.DataFrame(preds, columns = ['0','1','2'])
preds_df['pred'] = preds_df.idxmax(axis=1)
preds_df['actual'] = boost_data_set.iloc[0:breakpoint,boost_data_set.shape[1]-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The predictions are in order.